# Generate Token using Angular 2 client Library for Azure Oauth implementation for Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Is their any Angular 2/4 library/Sample Code available  for creating token for Client credential authentication in Azure Active Directory?

Comment: Client credential authentication is not used in Angular apps. It is for confidential clients only. The JS code runs on the user's device, so they would be able to get your app's client secret, which is bad. With Angular, you should use ADAL, and the implicit grant flow.

Comment: What is alternative way to secure web API and Angular 2...I know one way where we create JWT token from Authorize endpoint and send it to Web API using user credentials to generate token..but .We wanted application specific approach where we can generate application specific token and send it to server for authentication

Comment: What you could do is make a back-end API which acts as a proxy. It could use client credentials to get a token to call the actual API. But then again, what is the point? It would be almost the same thing to just have no authentication on the API.

Comment: Does ADAL js support application specific token generation activity..Just curious if it was possible or need to create custom code to generate token using angular js?

Comment: It's not possible